# Is comma a valid character in cookie-value

Tags: http, cookies

In some web server, cookie with a comma in value will be split into two cookie (one with empty value). For example, `"foo=bar,goo"` will be treated just like `"foo=bar;goo="`. Is this right according to RFC?

I find this RFC document but don't know exactly what it means.

```
cookie-pair       = cookie-name "=" cookie-value
cookie-name       = token
cookie-value      = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )
cookie-octet      = %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-3A / %x3C-5B / %x5D-7E
                   ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
                   ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
                   ; and backslash
```

[RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cookie-pair       = cookie-name "=" cookie-value
cookie-name       = token
cookie-value      = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )
cookie-octet      = %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-3A / %x3C-5B / %x5D-7E
                   ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
                   ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
                   ; and backslash
```

**What are those keywords: cookie-pair, cookie-name, cookie-value, cookie-octet?**

`cookie-value` is the right-side part of `=`.

`cookie-octet` is the real value, enclosed in double quotes or nothing. See:

```
key="value"
```

or

```
key=value
```

When you put in a `,` (or `;`) see what happens:

```
key="value,",key2="value2"
```

or

```
key=value,,key2=value2
```

So, your assumption is not quite correct and you must not use comma or semicolon inside the value.

Comment: Thank you. The web server I tested may be too "modern", while other platforms like PHP still allow comma as a valid value.

Comment: You must test it with **clients**, not with **servers**. It's for (backwards)compatibility for **clients** and interoperability between RFCs. From the servers perspective, you should never work with *tricks* to insert a second value, declare it properly.

Comment: Thank you again! But I like your old answer. :) I only wonder what the star near cookie-octet means.

Comment: @leetom I think the `*` means, that the value can be empty

Answer (score 9):

NO they are not allowed.

From the [specs](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html):

> This string is a sequence of characters excluding semi-colon, comma
>   and white space.

The same can be checked in  [RFC2965](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt) and  [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)

Comment: Thank you, but it is valid in platforms like PHP.

Comment: @leetom Protocol specifications are software independent. There is no functionality in PHP to ensure validity of HTTP response header fields.

Comment: Then those platforms are violating the specs.

Answer (score 3):

According to the document's part you quoted, commas are not allowed:

`US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs, whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon, and backslash`

However, I believe all modern browsers allow it anyway so use it at your risk.
You can always use base64 or something similar depending on your goal if you need to encode special characters and stay compliant.

Comment: But semicolon is also allowed according to the document, which is obviously wrong. So I wonder what does this mean.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. It's excluding these characters.

Comment: RFC 6265 was specifically written to consolidate the existing cookie RFCs of the time and clarify their rules based on *existing real-world usage*.  That includes the grammar.  So no, commas are not allowed in cookie values, and no browsers actually implemented that.

Answer (score 0):

The [6265 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1) spec and other similar specs are using the [ABNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) grammar:

```
cookie-octet      = %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-3A / %x3C-5B / %x5D-7E
                   ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
                   ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
                   ; and backslash
```

Lines that start with `;` are comments. They are helpful but have no grammatical meaning.

The slashes `/` separate alternatives.

Literal characters and ranges are specified using their octal representation:

```
%x21 is !
%x23-2B encompass the characters # $ % & ' ( ) * +
%x2D-3A encompass the characters - . / 0-9 :
%x3C-5B encompass the characters < = > ? @ A-Z [
%x5D-7E encompass the characters ] ^ _ ` a-z { | } ~
```

The comma code `0x2C` isn't included in any of the ranges, which makes it an invalid character to use in a `cookie-octet` or a `cookie-value`.